# can VirtualAlloc replace VirtualProtect

Tags: c, windows

VirtualAlloc function

Reserves, commits, or changes the state of a region of pages in the virtual address space of the calling process. Memory allocated by this function is automatically initialized to zero.

VirtualProtect function

Changes the protection on a region of committed pages in the virtual address space of the calling process.
To change the access protection of any process, use the VirtualProtectEx function.

As the above(from MSDN) says, VirtualAlloc can also change the protection state of committed pages as VirtualProtect. So i was wondering whether VirtualProtect can be replaced by VirtualAlloc.Thanks.

The following is an example of using VirtualAlloc to change the protection type of committed pages.

```
LPVOID lpAddress = NULL;
SIZE_T dwSize = 0x40000;
DWORD flAllocationType = MEM_COMMIT;
DWORD flProtect = PAGE_READWRITE;
LPVOID newAddress;
newAddress = VirtualAlloc(lpAddress, dwSize, flAllocationType, flProtect);
if(newAddress == NULL)
{

    printf("error %d occurs\n", GetLastError());
    return -1;
}
printf("allocation address is %p\n", newAddress);
lpAddress = (LPVOID)((int)newAddress + 0x8000);
newAddress = VirtualAlloc(lpAddress, dwSize, flAllocationType, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
if(newAddress == NULL)
{

    printf("error %d occurs\n", GetLastError());
    return -1;
}
printf("allocation address is %p\n", newAddress);
return 0;
```

Comment: *VirtualAlloc* can not change protection

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did test that the code above and the result shows that VirtualAlloc can change protection. You may have a try.

Comment: hm.. yes, *VirtualAlloc* really change protection. don't know about this before. however why so complex example ?

Comment: er, I should simplify the example.

Comment: I don't know about you, but I get ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS when I run that code. You may be able to commit multiple times, but not with a different page protection, at least not on Win10.